# Invalid password, please try again

Tags: login, password, kvm-virtualization

I'm running an Ubuntu 16.04 machine on QEMU/KVM.
I created a new user, atww, using Settings/User Accounts on the VM.
The user account type is Administrator.
I used usermod -p atww atww to set the password of user atww to atww.
When I try logging in with atww and password atww I get "Invalid password, please try again"
passwd -aS | grep atww 
gives
atww P 01/09/2018 0 99999 7 -1 which seems to be correct. Is it ?
Please help !
Many thanks, Arno

Comment: Try using `passwd` to set the user password

Answer (score 0):

The key **-p** for `usermod` command indicates to update the user's password with its encrypted value. https://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod

> -p, --password PASSWORD
>
> The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3).
>
> Note: This option is not recommended because the password (or encrypted password) will be visible by users listing the processes.
>
> You should make sure the password respects the system's password policy.

The solution is to use `passwd username`.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I used passwd as you suggested and got the problem solved.